# How to print Priority Queue vertically

Tags: java, algorithm

I would like to print a queue in the tree format. I realize converting to array then printing or using iterators print traversely but I want my output in the order below.

Input: priority queue of keys 1 -  10

**Tree**:

```
                      1
                   /     \
                 2         3
               /   \     /   \
              4     5   6     7
             /              /   \ 
            8              9     10
```

**Output**:

```
1
.2
..4
...8
..5
.3
..6
..7
...9
...10
```

So Essentially I am trying to represent the output as a tree format. Is there any inbuilt java method that can do this for me?

I tried solving these problem by creating new array for each tree level but I realize that it wouldn't be optimal especially if the queue has a large size.

Comment: How is this tree represented?

Comment: Same as in the question. 2 & 3 go under 1 and so on. This is a binary tree. I'm using a java.util.PriorityQueue

Comment: How do you know that the contents of a PriorityQueue is represented as a tree, and in particular the tree you drew in your question?

Comment: That is what I'm going for. The only difference in my tree and that represented by priority queue is the position of 9 and 10.

Comment: If the tree you want to display *isn't* what is in a priority queue (although presumably it has the same values), then what is the basis for choosing what tree to display?

Answer (score 1):

The output format which you want is known as [Pre-order Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) of a `Binary tree`. To get that output, you must store the numbers as a Binary Tree (not necessarily binary search tree) which takes `O(nlogn)` time and then you can easily computer this order using pre-order traversal. Time complexity of your whole program will be `O(nlogn)`

Comment: How do I store as Binary Tree here on Java?

Comment: I will personally suggest you make a `node` class which stores information about its `left child`, `right child` and its `data`. You can also add information about `parent` also.

Comment: Please could you give an example of an initialization? Also specify the family of the node. Thanks.

Comment: It will look something like `class node{ node left; node right; int data;}`

Answer (score 1):

The most common implementation of a priority queue is to store it in a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), which is a simple array, where the children of the item at index *i* are located at indices 2*i*+1 and 2*i*+2 (assuming the array is indexed starting at 0). That's not the only possible priority queue implementation, but it is simple, practical, and for most purposes the most efficient unless the priority queue is extraordinarily large or you need other primitives to be fast (such as merging two priority queues).

However, Java does not require the standard library to use this (or any) algorithm, and it therefore does not expose any internal information about a priority queue. The java.util.PriorityQueue is specified as an abstract datatype (ADT); an implementor is free to use whatever algorithm and underlying storage they find convenient, and it is not possible to directly access the underlying array (if there is one) nor to find the children of an item.

So if you need to do something which requires access to the priority queue implementation, you'll need to implement your own priority queue. There are innumerable examples of such an implementation and a simple web search should find you several [Note 1]

By contrast, the C++ standard library has explicit implementations of the binary heap primitives ([`make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), [`push_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [`pop_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap)) and its [priority queue class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is an adaptor over a randomly-accessible container using the binary heap primitives, so it does provide direct access to the underlying array.

That makes it possible to solve your problem easily enough in C++, and if you implemented a binary heap in Java, you could easily adapt the following code snippet to produce the output you wanted. This is a simple recursive depth-first walk over the implicit tree in the binary heap.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

template<typename V, typename C = std::vector<V>, typename Comp = std::less<V>>
class PrintablePriorityQueue : public std::priority_queue<V, C, Comp> {

  public:
    /* A real implementation would have more constructors :) */
    PrintablePriorityQueue() {}

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out, size_t i = 0, size_t depth = 0) const;
};

/* I left out the operator<< overload, which just calls print. With that,
   print would be made protected.
 */

template<typename V, typename C, typename Comp>
std::ostream& PrintablePriorityQueue<V, C, Comp>::print(std::ostream& out, size_t i, size_t depth) const {
  if (i < this->size()) {
    for (size_t j = depth; j; --j) out << '.';
    out << this->c[i] << '\n'; /* c is the underlying container */
    print(out, 2*i + 1, depth + 1);
    print(out, 2*i + 2, depth + 1);
  }
  return out;
}
```

And a simple driver:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  PrintablePriorityQueue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> queue;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) queue.push(atoi(argv[i]));
  queue.print(std::cout);
  return 0;
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
$ ./pq 1 9 4 7 2 8 3 5 6 10
1
.2
..5
...9
...6
..7
...10
.3
..8
..4
```

Note that a binary heap is always filled from left to right, so the diagram has a different shape from your sample.

---

#### Notes

1. Personally, I'd recommend taking a look at [Robert Sedgewick's excellent text book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X), particularly if it is the text book for the course you are taking, but any good algorithms text book is likely to describe the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual method that is going to format your code for you. Most likely you are going to have to find your own way to format the information either with a for loop, or something like that. Happy codin' :)

Answer (score 0):

I think for pre-order traversal of this kind of tree **recursion** is suitable.

For example (in C/C++) if you have `node` defined as

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node * left;
    node * right;
};
```

Recursive function for output can be (with C++ standard stream output) like

```cpp
void recursiveOut(node * root, int level = 0)
// root - pointer to the top of tree (subtree)
// level - level of recursion (equal the number of . before value)
{
    // check that node exists
    if (!root)
        return;
    // output data of current node (i.e. root)
    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
    {
        std::cout << ".";
    }
    std::cout << root->data << std::endl;
    // process the left branch
    recursiveOut(root->left, level + 1); // +1 for adding level
    // process the right branch
    recursiveOut(root->right, level + 1); // +1 for adding level
}
```

And it can be easily called as follows

```
int main(void)
{
    node * root = NULL;
    // init the tree
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        add(root, i);   // I suppose you have some functions to make tree
    recursiveOut(root); // output the tree
    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention, that in my solution `root` is checked once at the beginning of function (it is `if (!root)` which equal to `if (root == NULL)`) to prevent operations with non-existent object.

Perhaps, you find it useful to check `root->left` and `root->right` before recursive call for processing corresponding sub-trees, like

```
 if( root->left )
      recursiveOut(root->left, level + 1);
```